# Oracle Forms - "execute_query" command is very slow

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I have issue while executing some query in Oracle forms. My code looks like this:

```
--debug 0
next_block;
--debug 1
execute_query;
--debug 2
```

This code is from **KEY-NXTBLK** trigger. I'm outputting some log before **execute_query** command and after it. While executing query directly in the database it works just fine and I have result after **2 seconds**, but in Forms i have to wait **2 minutes** to get the results. Do you know why it takes so long to execute it in forms? Maybe I'm missing something there? Are any triggers executing along with execute_query command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which Forms version is it?

If it is 9i onwards, you can use its debug option and trace execution. How to enable it? Right-click left margin in the trigger you posted, set breakpoint to `NEXT_BLOCK`. Run the form in debug mode (it is a green *traffic light* icon placed right next to the one you use to run a form normally). Forms will stop here and let you proceed step-by-step (meaning: command-by-command). Then you'll see what is going on, which triggers are executed, how much time is spent on certain commands.

If you're on 6i, put `MESSAGE` calls into triggers so that you'd know what is being executed, in which order.

As of your question: `NEXT_BLOCK` itself might cause certain triggers to fire, such as `WHEN-VALIDATE-RECORD` (for a record in the "current" block), `PRE-BLOCK` (for the "next" block), `WHEN-NEW-RECORD-INSTANCE` (for the first record in the "next" block). `EXECUTE_QUERY` will cause `POST-QUERY` trigger to fire (used to populate non-database items), so if query returns many rows and trigger fires many times for each of them and it might take some time to complete.

Furthermore, try to restrict number of rows returned; open block's Property Palette, navigate to "Records" section and check properties and their values (for example, if "Query all records" is set to "Yes", set it to "No"). What is "Number of records buffered" set to? For more info about every property, click on it and press F1 to open Forms Online Help System.

Check block's `WHERE` clause, as well as `ORDER BY`. If they are somewhat complex, fetch might suffer.